# Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org

Tags: bnf, diagramming

I love the syntax of [railroad diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) on [json.org](https://www.json.org/) which are a graphical representation of the BNF language. I haven't found any tools that can produce results as eloquently.

### Can anyone identify the tool used to generate these diagrams?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There is an [**Online Railroad Diagram Generator**](https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui). It creates SVG [syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram), also known as railroad diagrams, from [context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) specified in [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF). You can copy the SVG code or take screen shots.

You have to type in the grammar and it'll make the diagram.

For example, to create the first railroad diagram you show, you would use the code:

```
object ::= '{' ((string ':' value ) ( ',' string ':' value )*)? '}'
```

[image]

Then you could go on to define `string` and `value` using `string ::= ...` and `value ::= ...` The references are all shown.

Check out some of the example diagrams on the page. They have XML and even EBNF itself.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the graphics into your own document other than a) making a screenshot b) copying the svg source from the page's source?

Comment: @rudolfson - You can write your own, the central logic isn't too bad, and all the code's there to see. Then just embed in your document. I wrote a WP plugin based on this. - The hardest part is making the graphics look nice.

Comment: The Online Railroad Diagram Generator mentioned here now offers a ZIP file with the PNG version of the generated diagrams.  Great tool!

Comment: It seems that the webapp moved here: http://bottlecaps.de/rr/

Answer (score 54):

> from       Douglas Crockford
>   to         Aleem B
>   date       Tue, Apr 28, 2009 at 6:01 PM
>   subject    Re: Railroad Diagrams on json.org
>
> I drew them with Visio. Creative
>   Docs.NET also works well.
>
> --
>
> Aleem B wrote:
>
> Hello Douglas,
>
> I thoroughly enjoy most things you put
>   out there and the railroad diagrams on
>   json.org are no different. I have been
>   trying to look around for a tool that
>   would generate diagrams nearly as
>   eloquent but have had no luck:
>
> [Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org)
>
> Is there some tool you used to convert
>   the BNF to these diagrams or were they
>   hand crafted?
>
> -- Aleem

Comment: For completions sake: [Tab Atkins Jr.](http://www.xanthir.com/) created  a [Javascript Railroad-diagram Generator](https://github.com/tabatkins/railroad-diagrams) using SVG. specifically because he could not find one that had the visual appeal he wanted , i.e. "the JSON.org look".

Answer (score 30):

[image]

[Tab Atkins Jr.](http://www.xanthir.com/) created  a **[Javascript Railroad-diagram Generator](https://github.com/tabatkins/railroad-diagrams)** using [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) specifically because he could not find one that had the visual appeal he wanted , i.e. "*the JSON.org look*".

Answer (score 9):

There was a similar question a few days ago:
[What is a good tool for creating railroad diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773371/what-is-a-good-tool-for-creating-railroad-diagrams)

That question was about how railroad diagrams in the SQLite syntax diagrams were generated. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773371/what-is-a-good-tool-for-creating-railroad-diagrams/773416#773416) found that the diagrams were generated using a DSL written in Tcl.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773371/what-is-a-good-tool-for-creating-railroad-diagrams/773453#773453) offered a suggestion to use a diagram generator which works off of EBNL grammar.

Comment: To add to that, there is also a list of tools in the Wikipedia article I link to. A true railroad diagram should not need arrows--if you imagine a train travelling those tracks it should be clear what routes you can or cannot take. And the json.org diagrams are just so pretty, I have to know if there's a tool for them =)

Have already seen these links but might helps others.

Comment: Sadly, "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation."

Comment: Nowadays SQLite uses [Pikchr](https://pikchr.org/), a tool made by SQLite's author.

Answer (score 5):

I have been looking also for the tools used to generate these [*Syntax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) Diagrams and if possible in `js library` so it can be edited and displayed without awaiting a boring time for a graphic to come.

I know there are tools [*out there*](https://www.google.com/search?q=railroad%20diagram&tbm=isch) but I would say that the generator from [*www.bottlecaps.de*](https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) has a nice graphic with color option. Unfortunately I could not get source code of the tool it self there.

I went also to the related questions of answers here but got only followings where we can get it as open source `js library` and provided with an online demo *[where we can try and play with](https://chetabahana.github.io/#chetabahana-skema)*.

- [railroad diagram generator](http://www.xanthir.com/etc/railroad-diagrams/generator.html) from [tabatkins](https://github.com/tabatkins/railroad-diagrams), in `js` (*Syntax* exists as a `Python` library as well)
- [js-sequence-diagrams](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/) from [bramp](https://github.com/bramp/js-sequence-diagrams), in `js` but [*UML*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) (*Syntax* is generated via *[www.bottlecaps.de](http://www.bottlecaps.de)*)
- [umlClass](http://www.gojs.net/latest/samples/umlClass.html) from [GoJS](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/sequenceDiagram.html), in `js` but found only for *UML*

Answer (score 4):

One of the things that IBM's railroad track generator handles well is default values.  I have not seen another generator that does this.

An example is

```
          ┌─────◀────┐┌(──«defaults»─)─┐                        
▶▶─COMMAND┴«argument»┴┼────────────────┼──────────────────────▶◀
                      │ ┌────◀─────┐   │                        
                      └(┴┬«option»┬┴┬─┬┘                        
                         └Help────┘ └)┘
```

Answer (score 4):

I found J-algo tool. I think it is very easy to draw diagram but I can't export to image or another type.

[image]

http://j-algo.binaervarianz.de/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/html-railroad-diagram/ which generates HTML railroad diagrams.  There is an [example](http://html-railroad-diagram.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/railroad.html) that shows the JSON railroad generated in an HTML page by JavaScript with links.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that IBM has a tool that builds such diagrams as part of their BookMaster SGML suite.  Railroad diagrams are often used in mainframe documentation.