# What program(s) generate grammar graphs?

Tags: image, grammar, graph-theory

I see grammar graphs on the websites for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) and [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  What program can be used to generate these pretty pictures?

Comment: "Railroad Diagrams", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773371/what-is-a-good-tool-for-creating-railroad-diagrams/773416#773416) found that SQLite uses [a custom script](http://www.sqlite.org/docsrc/artifact/46e904a66f) for the graphs on its website.  The graphs on json.org are [drawn in visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org/797828#797828).

Comment: SQLite custom script: Somebody had a nice weekend project. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they have some program that automates it, but you can make those kinds of graphs with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  I have done so in the past.