# What's the name for this type of flowchart?

Tags: charts, visio, flowchart

Take a look at this; it's very obvious how it works and what its purpose is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/number.gif))</sub>

1. What's this type of chart called?
2. Can I make this kind of chart in Visio?
3. What software do you recommend for making this kind of chart?

Comment: Although I know what it does, I wouldn't go that far as to call it "obvious".

Comment: Honestly, I think a regex is far more "obvious" than that diagram. `/-?([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]*)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]*)?/`

Comment: A regex isn't as universal as a railroad diagram. A regex requires someone to learn the syntax of a regex first, while a railroad diagram let's you dive in.

Comment: I didn't even stop to think for a second that you were joking. Man, I am dense. "I'm Dumbass material, Mr Dumbass." "It's Du-mas"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called a railroad diagram. It can more specifically be called a [syntax diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram). Not sure about Visio support but other tools can get the job done: [What is a good tool for creating railroad diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773371/what-is-a-good-tool-for-creating-railroad-diagrams)

[image]
<sub>(source: [antlr.org](http://www.antlr.org/works/screenshots/editor.jpg))</sub>

If you have a grammar file you can try to get it working in [ANTLR Works](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html), which is specifically built for working with the syntax and grammar of languages.

Answer (score 2):

These are called [Syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) (or railroad diagrams).

They can be created with Visio or [Creative Docs .NET](http://www.creativedocs.net/)

See here for more info:

[Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org)

Answer (score 1):

It is a [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) diagram; not sure if there is any visio addon to paint this kind of chart.