# Software for creating "Language Diagrams" structures

Tags: language-design, diagramming

In json.org website you can see several diagrams (which I don't know that correct term to describe) that shows the whole valid syntax of the language. For example http://json.org/object.gif

How do these diagrams called?

What software do you use to create them?

Thank you,
Maxim.

Comment: They are called "railroad" diagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Railroad/Syntax diagrams can be created by different software.

[Here](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) is a generator for Ruby.

[Here](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~thiemann/haskell/ebnf2ps/) is one in Haskell, and [one](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/realworld/syngen.html) in Latex.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org), the diagrams on the JSON website were created with Visio.

But I doubt it transforms BNF grammars into syntax diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you want, but [ANTLRWorks](https://web.archive.org/web/20121221164145/http://www.antlr.org:80/works/index.html) is an editor for the parser generator ANTLR that displays these diagrams on-the-fly:

[image: Antlrworks]
<sub>(source: [antlr.org](http://www.antlr.org/works/screenshots/editor.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I've seen them called both Syntax diagrams and Railroad diagrams -- there are tools out there for generating them, for example this one for [Ruby](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) or this plugin for [Latex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latexrail/)

Comment: What software do you think Douglas Crockford used when describing JSON? I have a home made created language which I would like to describe using "rail road".