# Parsing flow graph/parsing flowchart -- What is this called and how can I make them?

Tags: parsing, diagram, analysis, diagramming

I just got linked to [the JSON website](http://json.org/), and the images stunned me. A better way to intuitively show the flow of a parser I have never seen. Now I want to be able to make these diagrams for my own projects.

First of all, what is this type of diagram called?

Is there a program that can generate these, or am I on my own?

Comment: A little bit of googling based on answers shows that these are also called railroad diagrams. Now I have some better terms to use in searching--plenty of good results showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphical EBNF editor for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) grammars, [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html), automatically generates syntax diagrams of the rules you type.

For example, if you type the following rule (and `string` and `value` are also present!):

```
object 
  :  '{' ((string ':' value) | ',')* '}'
  ;
```

ANTLRWorks immediately displays the following diagram at the bottom of the page:

[image]

which you can enlarge and export in various formats (EPS or bitmap).

Comment: Awesome! Even better than what I was looking for because the diagram's source is actually the parsing code.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram

When I googled for Syntax Diagram Tool, there are several listed.

I have some minor experience with the graphvis tool, see their wide ranging gallery at [www.graphviz.org/Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! And a quick google actually points to a question similar to mine, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org