# What are these diagrams called? (answer : railroad diagrams)

Tags: diagram, sequence-diagram, diagramming

I have seen a lot of these diagrams in some help files and src documentation

What are they called? Are there any other (for same purpose) known diagrams?

[image]

Img source : http://www.sqlite.org/images/syntax/insert-stmt.gif

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org) has some more details on railroad diagrams, including a few links to some generation programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called  "railroad diagrams", because of their resemblance to a railroad track. They were often used to describe the grammar of older languages, before more formal grammars became routinely used. The problem with them is you can't easily feed them into tools like parser generators, or grammar checkers, so they are not used so much these days.

Answer (score 4):

They are called [syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram).

Comment: +1 you are right too, (but I have to choose only one), thanks!