# How to generate json.org-style images?

Tags: image

On [Json.org](http://json.org/) there are images that visualize the json syntax. How were they created?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org)