# Which Graphical Notation Is This?

Tags: modeling

What is the modeling language used in the official JSON website's home page [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeBVA.png)?

Example:

[image: http://www.json.org/object.gif]

Comment: FYI - it's a graphical notation, not a modeling language

Comment: Well, the diagram you posted here is called "syntax diagram"

Comment: It seems to be a visualization of *ABNF*, which is used in the JSON RFC (and other RFC's): https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4234.txt.

Comment: To be fair, I added the image. Maybe it was too much editing from my side, but since the OP explicitly referred to the website, I figured he meant those images. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: exact duplicate of: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179801/how-are-json-org-like-specs-graphs-called-and-how-can-i-generate-them also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't modelling.

It is documentation.

This style is called a [railroad or syntax diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram).