# What is the name of such diagrams?

Tags: diagram, sequences, flowchart

I would like to generate diagrams similar to this, but I don't have a clue what to look for.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**That's a [Syntax Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram).**

> Syntax diagrams (or railroad diagrams) are a way to represent a
>   context-free grammar.

Links:

- [How to read syntax diagrams](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7X_7.0.4/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/railroad_diagrams.htm)
- [Many examples](https://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html)
- [Creating syntax diagrams](https://superuser.com/questions/372019/program-for-creating-language-syntax-grammar-railroad-diagrams)

Answer (score 2):

These are called [syntax diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) or railroad diagrams for showing context free grammar

There is a [tool](http://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) which can convert BNF notation to railroad diagrams